# does my machine configuration make sense?

Tags: configuration, central-processing-unit, memory, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

i couldn't think of a better place to ask this question, so here it goes. we're putting together a dedicated server for a website that will initially host the web server and the mysql database. as the website grows, we'll move the database to a different server and this machine will eventually only server the actual website.

so the question is ...does my configuration look okay? it's the first time i'm building a server from scratch so i want to make sure i don't combine components that don't fit or something. things like ..do the drives i picked work for the hot swap ..etc.

what do you guys think? am i good to go with this configuration? :)

Chassis: Supermicro SuperServer 6016T-MTHF (6x DDR3 SDRAM - ECC DIMM 240-pin, 2x LGA1366 Socket, Power Provided:  600 Watt, 4 (free) x hot-swap - 3.5")

CPU: Intel BX80614E5620 Xeon E5620 Processor - 4 Core, 2.40GHz, LGA 1366, 5.86GT/s QPI
12MB Cache, 64-Bit, 80W, HyperThreading

Memory: Crucial CT51272BB1339 4GB PC10600 DDR3 Memory - 1333MHz, ECC, Registered, 1x4096MB (possibly 3 or  4 of them)

Hard Drives: Western Digital WD2002FAEX Caviar Black Hard Drive - 2TB, 3.5", SATA 6Gbps, 7200 RPM, 64MB (possibly 2 or 3).

thank you very much for any professional advice :)

Comment: With 2 disks you could arrange a RAID1 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We don't do product recommendation on serverfault normally.

Your CPU uses tree memory channels, this means you will need memory that supports triple channels AND you will need to use the memory in pairs of 3.

Comment: Thanks :) So if I use 3x 4GB modules, I should be okay?

Comment: yes indeed thats correct